# Integral of Gaussian Curvature over a Tube

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, curvature

I am working on a problem which I have come to a standstill on. The question reads:

> Let $\alpha(s)$ be a closed regular curve in $\mathbb{R}^3$ parametrized by arc-length. Consider the tube:
>   $$X(s,v)=\alpha(s)+r(n(s)\cos(v)+b(s)\sin(v))$$
>   Where $n(s)$ and $b(s)$ represent the normal and binormal vectors of $\alpha(s)$. Integrate the Gaussain Curvature over the Tube.

Now I found the Gaussian Curvature (which was very tedious) and got the answer:
$$K(s,v) = -\frac{\kappa(s)\cos(v)}{r(1-r\kappa(s)\cos(v))}$$
Where $\kappa(s)$ denotes the curvature of $\alpha(s)$. Now, how am I supposed to Integrate this over anything? I'm assuming that I should use Stokes', as it is the only thing that makes sense to do. So should I just consider $dK(s,v)$? and then consider the tube $T=\partial M$ as the boundary of a solid Tube $M$?

Comment: You run into trouble if you try to use Stokes' theorem. If you pick $M=T$ then you need to prove that there exist a 1-form $\omega$ such that $K ds \wedge dv = d\omega$. If you pick $M$ to be the filled tubular region. Then you have the issue that you cannot compute $d (K ds \wedge dv)$ in the interior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Gauss-Bonnet:

\begin{align*}
 \int_M KdA = 2\pi\chi(M).
\end{align*}

Now the surface you discribe (somthing like a cylinder or torus) we have that $\chi(M)=0$. Thus $\int_M KdA =0$.